# How can I find my browser web log file?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

For a project I need to analyze my browser web log file data. But I don't know where it resides and how to get data from it? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Project Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) answers your question very well. However I will condense the information to only what you want.

### Browser Web logs : Where they reside ?

Debug logs are stored in the user data directory as **`chrome_debug.log`** and this file is overwritten every time Chrome restarts. However you can stop the file from being overwritten by moving it to the desktop. So, [Default User Data Directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#default-location) for various platforms are :

#### 1. On Windows

The default location is in the `local app data` folder :

```
[Chrome] %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data
[Chromium] %LOCALAPPDATA%\Chromium\User Data
```

#### 2. On MacOSX

In the `Application Support` folder :

```
[Chrome] ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome
[Chromium] ~/Library/Application Support/Chromium
```

#### 3. On Linux

In the `~/.config` folder :

```
[Chrome Stable] ~/.config/google-chrome
[Chrome Beta] ~/.config/google-chrome-beta
[Chrome Dev] ~/.config/google-chrome-unstable
[Chromium] ~/.config/chromium
```

For More Platforms, [Visit this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#default-location).

---

For your Project, If you need you can [Override the User Data Directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#overriding-the-user-data-directory) by typing this at command line

```
[Windows] chrome.exe --user-data-dir=c:\foo
[Linux]   google-chrome --user-data-dir=/path/to/foo
[Windows] chromium-browser --user-data-dir=c:\foo
[Linux]   chromium-browser --user-data-dir=/path/to/foo
```

### Browser Web logs : How to enable and get data from it ?

By default, browser debug logs aren’t generated, so you’ll need to [enable logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) using [command-line flags](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/command-line-flags).

```
--enable-logging --v=1
```

Before using chrome_debug.log in a project, be aware that it `can contain some personal information`, such as URLs opened during that session of chrome.

Since the debug log is a `human-readable text file`, you can open it up with a text editor (notepad, vim, etc..) and use it just like the test file.

Also, the `boilerplate values` enclosed by brackets on each line are in the format :

> [ process_id : thread_id : ticks_in_microseconds : log_level : file_name(line_number) ]

That would help in some way or other in your project.

Comment: Did logs move on macOS @C0deDaedalus  directories=.metadata_never_index          Default/                       MEIPreload/                    Safe Browsing Cookies          Subresource Filter/
Address Validation Rules       External Extensions/           NativeMessagingHosts/          Safe Browsing Cookies-journal  TLSDeprecationConfig/
BrowserMetrics-spare.pma       FileTypePolicies/              OriginTrials/                  SafetyTips/                    Webstore Downloads/
CertificateRevocation/         First Run                      PepperFlash/                .....(way more)

Comment: Looks like logs have moved on Mac but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 0):

From [Chrome for enterprise Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271282?hl=en)
Debug logs are stored in the user data directory as chrome_debug.log.

By default, browser debug logs aren’t generated, so you’ll need to [enable logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging)

Answer (score 0):

If you closed ALL chrome processes (sometimes extensions still run even Chrome is closed, you need to close them too as I believe)

If you enabled logging:

```
--enable-logging
```

(`--log-level=0`     -   doesn't dump lots of system info in a log)

and still can't find log file - look in environment variables. There it is: `CHROME_LOG_FILE`

Comment: Nothing seems to get logged unless --v=1 is passed as well.