# How to stop running a program (like Chrome) from an external SSD

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, ssd

A few years ago, I did something that enabled me to install the Chrome browser on an external SSD and run it from there. Apologies for being about as unspecific as it gets!

Because I don't remember what I did, I can't undo it. The result is that now that the SSD is no longer connected to my computer, I am unable to install Chrome. To be precise, after a fresh install, it crashes the moment I try to run it.

So what did I do and how can it be undone? Thanks to whoever takes pity on a fool like me.

> Gantendo: During installation, you can simply choose the location
> where you want to install Chrome. Am I correct in thinking that what
> you did was more involved than that?

It sure was. Chrome did not allow installing on an external SSD without me doing whatever I did.

> Ramhound: Have you tried to delete the user profile which points to
> the Chrome installation that no longer exists?

OMG! That did it! Thank you so much, Ramhound

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95319?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&sjid=1579371280376600133-EU

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6315198?hl=en&ref_topic=7438629&sjid=1579371280376600133-EU

Comment: During installation, you can simply choose the location where you want to install Chrome. Am I correct in thinking that what you did was more involved than that?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1286937/how-can-i-find-my-browser-web-log-file

Comment: Have you tried to delete the user profile which points to the Chrome installation that no longer exists?